# How to build a WHILE Loop using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have loaded the column names from a table into the temporary table called `#COLUMN_NAMES`. I would like to build a while loop that passes each of the rows from the temp table through my `#Data_Quality_Check` table that I created below.

There are 54 rows of column_names in my table `#Column_names` currently. Ideally I would like to have the while loop process each of the variables and put the output into the `#Data_Quality_Check` table.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#COLUMN_NAMES') is not null
    drop table #COLUMN_NAMES

SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS Column_Names 
INTO #COLUMN_NAMES
FROM information_schema.columns     
WHERE table_name = 'ssrs_sourcedata'

----- >>>>  !!!!!! INSERT CODE TO BUILD WHILE LOOP !!!!

if object_id('tempdb..#DATA_QUALITY_CHECK') is not null
    drop table #DATA_QUALITY_CHECK

SELECT  
    periodenddate,
    '@Column_Name' AS Label,
    MIN(@Column_Name) AS Min_Value,
    MAX(@Column_Name) AS Max_Value,
    SUM(@Column_Name) AS Sum_Value,
    AVG(@Column_Name) AS Avg_Value, 
    SUM(Case when @Column_Name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS Null_Count,
    SUM(Case when len(cast(@Column_Name AS VARCHAR)) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Space_Count,
    MAX(len(cast(@Column_Name AS VARCHAR))) AS max_length,
    MIN(len(cast(@Column_Name AS VARCHAR))) AS min_length 
INTO 
    #DATA_QUALITY_CHECK    
FROM 
    dbcrms.report.ssrs_sourcedata 
WHERE 
    periodenddate = '2017-06-30'  
GROUP BY 
    periodenddate
```

Comment: Looks like maybe a good case for a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic that badboy. You need to create the empty temp table first though

```
declare @cnt int = 1;
declare @mcnt int;
declare @vsql varchar(2000);
declare @column_name varchar(100);

select @mcnt = count(*)    
from #COLUMN_NAMES;

while @cnt <= @mcnt
begin
select  @column_name = column_names
from 
(
select column_names, row_number() over(order by column_names) rn
from #COLUMN_NAMES
)
where rn = @cnt;

set @vsql = 'insert into #DATA_QUALITY_CHECK (Label, min_value, max_value, sum_value, avg_value, null_count, space_count, max_length, min_length)
SELECT periodenddate, ''' + @Column_Name + ''' AS Label, 
MIN(' + @Column_Name+ ') AS Min_Value, 
MAX(' + @Column_Name + ') AS Max_Value,
SUM(' + @Column_Name + ') AS Sum_Value,
AVG(' + @Column_Name + ') AS Avg_Value, 
SUM(Case when ' + @Column_Name + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS Null_Count,
SUM(Case when len(cast(' + @Column_Name + ' AS VARCHAR)) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Space_Count,
MAX(len(cast(' + @Column_Name + ' AS VARCHAR))) AS max_length,
MIN(len(cast(' + @Column_Name + ' AS VARCHAR))) AS min_length 
FROM dbcrms.report.ssrs_sourcedata WHERE periodenddate = '2017-06-30'  
GROUP BY periodenddate ';

execute(@vsql);
set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;
```

Comment: This is the error that I got when I tried to run this.                                 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '@mcnt'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '@column_name'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.

Comment: @DanielBailey the `over` was a typo, supposed to be brackets (look up window functions). My tSQL is a bit rusty